# Booksleeve, error thrown when trying to open connection after connection was closed

Tags: c#, redis, booksleeve

I cannot re-connect to my Redis DB doing the following:

- Create a new `RedisConnection` called "connection"
- Open the connection `connection.Open().Wait();`
- Close the connection `connection.Close(true);`
- Now when I attempt to `connection.Open().Wait();` an error is thrown "Connection is closed".

I am aware the connection was closed but why I cannot re-open it?

The same happens if I instead of close the connection, shut down the Redis server, let the client raise the `Closed` event, re-start the server, and then attempt to open the connection with `connection.Open().Wait();` again. "Connection is closed" error is thrown.

What is wrong with my approach? I do not seem to be able to manage connection states properly with Booksleeve.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the expected usage that you open and close a BookSleeve connection.

- since it is a multiplexer, it is expected that it is opened once and then used by multiple callers concurrently (it is thread-safe etc)
- opening involves various handshakes (at both network and protocol levels) to ensure correct operation - this is best avoided (it isn't insanely expensive, note)
- no ongoing state would be viable once closed; you night as well just use a brand new connection if you really want to close it

Personally I'd only close it if I was reconfiguring the system at runtime, or the connection broke.

Comment: Exactly what I want to use it for, at least the open method when a connection broke down, but it does not work. So, I guess I would just instantiate a new connection?

Comment: @Freddy indeed - just "new" one up

Comment: @MarcGravell It would be great if you could provide an implementation for resilient connection. Doesn't need to be part of the library. Recommended setup on wiki or here would be enough.